# How to download a 32-bit version of Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: system-installation, 32-bit

How do you download a 32-bit version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Related: [What options do I have to upgrade an unsupported i386 version of Ubuntu to an operating system with newer packages?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1361769/124466)

Answer (score 1):

You can download a 32-bit version of the [Ubuntu **`mini.iso`**](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13211730#post13211730) file of all current versions, also 18.04 LTS.

- If you install the program package `ubuntu-desktop` into this system (during or after installing the minimal ubuntu system), you will get Ubuntu with its standard desktop. But since it is not part of the official releases, it is not debugged, and there may be things that do not work correctly.
- If you have an old computer with a 32-bit system, you will probably get better performance with a community flavour with a light desktop environment,

  - Lubuntu
  - Ubuntu Budgie
  - Ubuntu MATE
  - Xubuntu

  and these community flavours provide 32-bit iso files.