# Ubuntu GNOME 2 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, server, gnome

How to install Ubuntu GNOME 2 desktop on Ubuntu Server 14.04.06 LTS (Without pre-installed desktop)?
Gnim

Gnome 2, Not 3, and not alternative KDE or XFCE!

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 has reached the end of its life. It is not supported any more. Old unsuported versions of Ubuntu are off topic here.

Comment: Yesterday you asked about [Ubuntu 16.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1460293/ubuntu-16-10-want-boot-after-installation), which was closed with the same reason this will be. It's OK if you want to start a computer museum, but please familiarize with the guidelines for this site. Good luck! 

Comment: What are the specifications of your computer? If your computer cannot run recent versions of Ubuntu, we can suggest alternative operating systems.

Comment: See [What options do I have to upgrade an unsupported i386 version of Ubuntu to an operating system with newer packages?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1361769/124466)

Comment: GNOME 2 used GTK2 which is *deprecated*, GTK4 is where the *development* now is & GTK3 (used by GNOME3) is in *maintenance* mode.   The only GTK2 desktop that now exists is LXDE  (the *devs* of LXDE switched to Qt5 as GTK3 was heavier they blogged & thus LXDE's replacement is LXQt...)  You didn't say what you wanted GNOME 2 for, but there are other GTK2 alternatives (*LXDE used as example here*)  Ubuntu *trusty* uses GTK3 so won't run GNOME2

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 14.04 has reached end of life in 2019.

The GNOME 2 desktop interface was forked into the MATE desktop.

If you want to use GNOME 2 interface, use [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/).

[image]

Comment: Good answer for a question doomed for closure..

Comment: Great answer... alas the switch of MATE desktop from GTK2 to GTK3 was very much noticed by me on my old pentium M laptops (*i386*), the slow down being enough that I *jumped* ship on those prehistorical museum pieces (*i386 or 32-bit x86 hardware*).  MATE was a little better on pentium 4/D (*dual core but also i386*) though...   Note MATE's fault, it was the GTK switch, so I opted for other GTK2 alternatives when using *i386*.

Comment: Gnome 2, not any alternative

Comment: It is not available anymore. MATE is built upon GNOME 2, and looks very similar.