# Compatiblity with Ubuntu

Tags: compatibility

I'm already getting closed answers for unsupported versions of Ubuntu.
But what do I do? I have a 2012 PC, 2G RAM, an old processor (i386 architecture). Not surprising: non-compatible with new versions of Ubuntu. I'm still more impressed with Ubuntu... I can't tell.

Comment: Your question makes no sense to me, but I use hardware as old as from 2005 in *Quality Assurance* testing of all releases of Ubuntu Desktop & *flavors* of Ubuntu, including some with 2GB of RAM, and all releases run  (*though on some video cards I'd be more selective than with others in choices*)

Comment: Your PC will work just fine with Lubuntu or maybe Xubuntu. Try it out.

Comment: Also any release run, but not run without lags

Comment: FYI:  I'm involved with *flavors* inc. already mentioned.. Both Lubuntu & Xubuntu are used to QA-test on `lenovo thinkpad sl510 (c2d-t6570, 2gb, i915)` & like hardware (that's not my oldest, selected as it's a box with only 2GB of RAM) but I'd decide on more than just machine specs as to which I'd use (*though the machine mentioned has both installed in a multi-desktop install*)

Comment: To avoid lag, you need the apps used to dictate which desktop will perform best; ie. you need the apps to share the same libraries/toolkits as the desktop itself; Xubuntu is a GTK desktop, Lubuntu is a Qt desktop; thus select based on apps... Also FYI:  Lubuntu may need some tweaking (esp. with regards swap) for best performance; Xubuntu may too - but Lubuntu more so (*depending on release & version of `calamares` used)

Comment: "I'm already getting closed answers for unsupported versions of Ubuntu." don't blame us for that ;-) i386 on Ubuntu is basically dead. If you need that: go for gentoo or debian. "But what do I do?" is also pfftopic as you are asking for opinions... we can't decide for you. I would buy a new machine. 200 euro gets you a quicker machine that you have now.

Comment: Advice: The main issue is 32-bit hardware. You must migrate to an OS that supports your hardware. Debian still supports 32-bit systems, complete with a 32-bit installer. Ubuntu does not anymore, due to a lack of 32-bit users among the volunteer and developer communities.

Comment: Try a lightweight os like https://antixlinux.com/

Answer (score 4):

This is actually rather straightforward: Ubuntu no longer provides support for 32-bit architecture.

This means:

1. Either buy new hardware that Ubuntu supports (like AMD64)
2. Use another Linux distribution that still supports 32-bit hardware. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1361769/124466) question for more details.

In general, you should probably look for advice elsewhere, like [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) to broaden your possibilities.

Comment: where do you see from the question, that OP has 32 bit?

Comment: I know, because he posted 2 previous questions about this already. I added it to the question, because it's a fact from previous questions.

Comment: That is was OP said, that he used. But a PC from 2012 should have 64 bit, or no?

Comment: I tried to make the question understandable based on previous facts. The OP is welcome to make correctional edits.

Comment: I do agree with your dupe suggestion though..

Comment: He keeps adding questions not liking the answer deleting them and adding new ones.

Comment: @pLumo 2012 was still an era where there *were* i386 and not amd64 processors, so if OP has been posting the same question repeatedly it's safe to make that assumption that it's a 32bit only if it's their statements specifically.

Comment: Sure, they still exist. But almost all consumer processors from Intel and AMD had 64 bit from ~2006 on. I had an Athlon64 in 2004.